# Is there a way to enforce that only merges which conform to this branch strategy will be accepted by a github repository?

Tags: git, github

I like the branch strategy outlined via [this blog post](https://blog.carbonfive.com/always-squash-and-rebase-your-git-commits/).

The strategy is reasonably easy to explain, encourages people to learn the most important parts of git for a reasonable workflow, and avoids a lot of gotchas that are otherwise going to be encountered and re-encountered by non-expert git users in a reasonably sized team inclusive of many junior developers.

I would like to move my team towards this strategy -- and I would provide guard-rails so that folks can 'learn' the correct strategy by trying to do.  So I want to enforce that *only* commits conforming to this branching strategy are allowed to be merged to the master/production branch.

Is there a way to enforce conformance to this merge strategy for a branch in a GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't offer an option to limit the number of commits, but you can require that branches are up to date before merging.  If you really want to limit it to a single commit, then you can enforce that in your CI system by running something like this (substituting the variables with your CI system's):

```
test $(git rev-list $BASE..$HEAD | wc -l) -eq 1
```

To use the GitHub up-to-date branch check, go into the repository settings, choose Branches and add a protected branch (which is usually your default branch).  Then choose “Require status checks to pass before merging” and “Require branches to be up to date before merging”.

I will point out that many experienced developers prefer to write multiple logical bisectable commits and squashing those will remove useful information from those commits and their commit messages.  However, if you want to do that anyway, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: Id be fine enforcing only that the branches are up to date prior to merging -- how would that be enforced?

Comment: The encouragement to squash commits can be just an encouragement -- benefit being that it makes it easier for the developer to resolve any conflicts encountered during rebase -- easier with most tools if commits are squashed to avoiding having to resolve conflicts multiple times during rebase